# save textarea into database and send email keeping the text area format

Tags: php, mysql, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

through cakephp, I save a text area which will be used as an email message into a database.
I can save it correctly, but when I tried to pull the data from database, and send an email using that data, the email I received is in a 1 long line of text, instead of keeping the format how I typed it in the text area. Is it possible to keep the format to send an email?

e.g: if in text area I typed something like:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

The email I got will be

```
This is line 1. This is line 2. This is Line 3.
```

What I want is what I typed:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

This is the code:
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

```
    $recipients = str_replace(' ', '', $recipients);
    $recipients = explode(',', $recipients);
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from($user_email);
    $email->to($recipients);
    $email->subject($final_subject);
    $email->template('download_link_email');
    $email->emailFormat('both');
    $email->viewVars(array('url' => $this->generateUrl('datas', 'download', $group_id, $user_id, $email_id), 'final_subject' => $final_subject, 'final_recipient' => $final_recipients, 'final_message' => $final_message));
    $email->send();
```

and the download_link_email template

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $final_subject; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $final_subject; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $final_message; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $this->Html->link('Click here to download', $url);?>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As for how the text area get saved to database, it's standard cakephp style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';
$final_message = str_replace($order, $replace, $final_message);
```

you can check the [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for more info on str_replace

OR you can use [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) (thanks to **eggyal** for pointing it out)

```
nl2br($final_message)
```

Comment: didn't know about that one, but seems to be roughly the same